# subquery using SQLiteQueryBuilder

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to use `SQLiteQueryBuilder` to build a query ,I know I can reach that using `rawQuery`, the query has a `subQuery`, I try to do that I don't get any error but no result at all too,

the query is somethig like that

`SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE a = (SELECT b FROM TABLE2 WHERE id = 1);`

`SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(database,null,selection,selectionArgs,null,null,null,null,null);`

where selection is "a=?" 
and
selectionArgs is="SELECT b FROM TABLE2 WHERE id=1";

Comment: WHERE a **IN** (SELECT ...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `?` and bind args for literals only, not for expressions or subqueries. The subquery you're trying to bind is really bound as a string literal so the query really becomes something similar to

```
... WHERE a='SELECT b FROM TABLE2 WHERE id=1'
```

So don't use `?` for that.

You probably also want `IN` instead of `=`:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE a IN (SELECT b FROM TABLE2 WHERE id=1);
```

In here you can use `?` bind args for the `id`:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE a IN (SELECT b FROM TABLE2 WHERE id=?);
```

You can possibly construct a query like that with `SQLiteQueryBuilder` but as said, it's more straightforward to just use `rawQuery()`.